# history.push throwing error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): history.push is not a function" in action creator using withRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx, redux-form, react-router-dom

When handling the submit here on this form component that uses redux-form there is an error happening when, upon receiving a success promise on the action creator, the user is not redirected to `/contacts` as an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): history.push is not a function` is generated. How do I/do I need to pass the history state to the `ContactForm` component so that the user can be properly redirected? I have verified the form is submitting successfully to the API and storing in the database correctly. The error is only with the `history.push`.

**ContactForm component**

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ContactField from "./ContactField";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import formContactFields from "./formContactFields";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as actions from "../../actions";

class ContactForm extends Component {
    renderFields() {
        return _.map(formContactFields, ({ label, name, value, type }) => {
            return <Field 
                    key={name} 
                    component={ContactField} 
                    label={label} 
                    name={name} 
                    type={type}
                    value={value}
                />
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-container">
                <form
                    onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.addContact)}
                >
                    {this.renderFields()}
                    <Link 
                        to="/contacts" 
                        className="btn red darken-1 btn-flat white-text"
                    >
                        <i className="material-icons left">arrow_back</i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </Link>
                    <button 
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn cyan darken-1 btn-flat white-text right"
                    >
                    <span>Add</span>
                    <i className="material-icons right">add</i>
                </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

ContactForm = reduxForm({
    form: "newContactForm",
})(ContactForm);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {actions})(withRouter(ContactForm));
```

**Actions**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { FETCH_USER } from "./types";

export const addContact = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/contacts", values);

    history.push("/contacts"); // THE ERROR IS HAPPENING HERE
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`history` will obviously be `undefined` since you haven't passed the value to the action in anyway. It gets `values` automatically because `redux-form`'s `handleSubmit` passes them to whatever function you give it. In order to pass extra values, you'll need to restructure how you pass the function to `handleSubmit`.

You get to define the function that's passed to `handleSubmit`. So since your action needs access to the form values *and* `history`, you can just declare a middle function that adds the extra values.

```js
onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit((values) => this.props.addContact(values, this.props.history))}
```

Or to clean it up you can move it out of the inline like this:

```js
submit = (values) => {
  this.props.addContact(values, this.props.history);
}

...


onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit)}
```